# AlarmManager not calling BroadcastReceiver precisely every interval

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have the following `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class LocationUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationHelper locationHelper = new LocationHelper(context);
        locationHelper.updateLocation();

        //.. do stuff with location

    }

    public static void SetAlarm(Context context, Long time){
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateReceiver.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), time, pi);
    }

    public static void CancelAlarm(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}
```

I call the setAlarm method like this to test from an Activity:
LocationUpdateReceiver.SetAlarm(this, 3000L);

You will notice I call `setRepeating()` which I thought was supposed to call the receiver class exactly every 3 seconds?

The trouble is that more often then not it doesn't call the receiver for over 5 minutes, this is quite a large deviation. I intend to run the receiver every 30 minutes, but should I expect a comparative percentage in deviation time?

How can I make sure that it will get called exactly (or with very small deviation) to the interval I specify?

Comment: since API 19, the alarm manager is called inexact. instead of setRepeating, You may use setExact and do the repeats by Yourself programmatically.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs `the alarm manager is called inexact`, Hard to believe that would cause almost 5 minutes delay, don't think that is the (only) problem, or am I wrong?

Comment: if You are really sure that Your "time" variable is correct, then what else? Yes, 5 minutes seem to be a very long time, but like described in the API, "the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use"....have You checked that Your "time" is set correct?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thanks for the info, I was just currious ;)

Comment: no problem....it´s allways a heavy task if something that You know for years changes in the API.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your
>   application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time
>   exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy
>   applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms,
>   treated as exact.

You can use [setExact()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and set the intervals yourself.

Comment: Does this allow recurring calls of the broadcast receiver?

Comment: No, the recurrence has to be set by you.

Comment: Cant see reason for approving this as correct answer